# "\Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container."

Tags: 8, testing, symfony-services

I am attempting to write a PHPUnit test for a service of mine.

My test looks like the following.

```
class CustomServiceTest extends UnitTestCase {

  public function testDefaultBehavior() {
    $service = new CustomService(\Drupal::service('custom_utils.some_resolver'), \Drupal::configFactory());
    $service->execute();
  }
}
```

However, it raises the following exception.

```
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerNotInitializedException:
\Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to mock the services you will be using in your test, so that they return values. You can do that as follows:

```
public function testDefaultBehavior() {
  $some_resolver = $this->getMockBuilder('Drupal\namespace\for\custom_utils\someresolver')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
  $config_factory = $this->getMockBuilder('Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
    $service = new CustomService($some_resolver, $config_factory);
```

}

Note that you should use the actual interface (or class if you have no interface) instead of `Drupal\namespace\for\custom_utils\someresolver`

You'll need to set up expectations to return the values from the services you mocked. You can read more on that here:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/understanding-phpunit-expectations